# TP player in 1.15.2 relative to the player, not the command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

It says it all in the title. Anything I try (using /teleport, using /execute) teleports the player relative the command block. I just want the player to teleport to y=46 when I power a command block. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Teleport all entities relative to themselves in 1.13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336262/teleport-all-entities-relative-to-themselves-in-1-13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the point of execution, you can use the "at" keyword. Example:

```
/execute as <player> at @s run tp ~ 46 ~
```

Comment: Commands had always been executed at the position of the executor by default, except `/tp`. Now `/tp` works correctly as well. It was a bugfix that changed this.

Comment: I thought that wasn't the case because of how /tp worked. Thanks for pointing this out.