# Tp help (minecraft 1.13)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I'm making something where a command block teleports a player a certain amount above the player. If I use the command `/tp @p ~ ~1 ~`, it teleports me above the command block. Any help would be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Teleport all entities relative to themselves in 1.13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/336262/teleport-all-entities-relative-to-themselves-in-1-13)

Answer (score 0):

If you only use relative coordinates (~) in a tp command, The entity will get teleported to the location where the command got executed example the command block. To change that, I suggest you to use `/execute as <entity> at @s run <your command>`.

Example   `/execute as @p at @s run tp @s ~ ~1 ~`

I hope that solve your problem!

Comment: Don't answer duplicate questions.

Comment: why not? isn´t it my choice if i want to answer or not? you doesn´t get affected if i answer or  do you? i just tryied to help :(